# Getting error in downloading repository Magento 2 via composer

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.4.1

I am using windows 10 and node js command prompt with latest composer version. The xampp already install with supporting magento2 PHP directives.

When i am trying to install a new magento 2 version 2.4.x and type the command this

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <mydirectory>`

I got the following error:

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer-root-update-plugin[1.0.0].

```
- magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].

```
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Problem 3
- laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4] require composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.

```
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4].

- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.1].
```

Any ideas how to get solution around this?

Comment: Which composer version are you using? I think you should use composer version 1.

Comment: My composer version is latest 2.x.

Answer (score 6):

You should use composer version 1.x.

Install latest release of version 1.x.

```
composer self-update --1
```

and you can try install magento.

If you want to return to Composer 2 again.

```
composer self-update --2
```